# Difference between f(x) and f(x,y)?

Tags: calculus

I recently started doing calculus and came across terms such as f(x) and f(x,y). What is the difference between them? Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is a function of a single variable. For example, $f(x)=x^2$

$f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables. For example, $f(x)=x^2y+xy$.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same thing. $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$, e.g., $f(x,y) = 3x + \sin(y)$. But $f(x)$ is a function of only one variable, e.g., $f(x) = x^3$.

Answer (score 0):

In higher-level calculus, functions have multiple variables plugged into them and are charted using $(x,y,z)$! For example, if you wanted to graph the height of your driveway, you could use $h(w,l)$ where $w$ is a point on the width and $l$ is a point on the length. Check out Wolfram|Alpha for more of that stuff. They'll even let you try graphing some of your own $x$-$y$-$z$ functions!